# Non-singular rings which are Rickart

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, projective-modules

A ring $R$ is said to be a *right Rickart ring* if the right annihilator of any element in $R$ is of the form $eR$ for some idempotent $e \in R$.
It turns out that a ring $R$ is right Rickart iff every principal right ideal of $R$ is projective as a right $R$-module. (Prop. 7.48 in Lam - "Lectures on Modules and Rings".)

Recall that a ring $R$ is a *right non-singular ring* if the left annihilator of each essential right ideal of $R$ is zero.

> **Question:**
>   For a ring $R$, being right Rickart implies being right non-singular (loc.cit., p.262).
>   The converse (right non-singular $\Rightarrow$ right
>   Rickart), however, does not hold in general. What would be (a candidate for) the mildest possible
>   assumption that one can impose on $R$ and get that the converse holds?